# Issue in file access with absolute paths

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've created a .NetCore console application in which am trying to check if a file exists using its absolute path, but am facing issues, I always get a false response even though the file exists. Even though I pass absolute path as parameter to API, it always prefixes the current working directory, so the path gets evaluated as doesn't exists.

I'm running this code on a windows 10 desktop and the application is created using .NetCore 2.1. I've tried various different methods to evaluate the existence of file like FileInfo Class instance and File.Exists static method. They've failed so far. I've diagnosed the issue, but I couldn't find a way to fix it.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace FileAccess
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"‪D:\ScriptData\test.zip");
            Console.WriteLine($"Full Name: {fileInfo.FullName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"FileInfo.Exists: {fileInfo.Exists}");
            Console.Write($"File.Exists with @: {File.Exists(@"‪D:\ScriptData\test.zip")}")
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the code is:

```
Full Name: D:\Work\Samples\FileAccess\FileAccess\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\?D:\ScriptData\test.zip
False
False
```

Even though am passing the absolute path, it prefixes the current working directory to the path I've passed. I've checked the Access to the file, its all fine, still I get false as response for both the cases.

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dLnF.png)

[Screenshot of Debug Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP96g.png)

Comment: @Sk83r1l4m4 I tried your suggestion, its still not working. But even if it worked wont help my case, since I've to pass the path as command line argument. What I've shared is a sample code. I've checked for permission, its not the issue.

Comment: Upvoted because you did the right thing to cut and paste your original source code, which revealed the problem of an invisible LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING character in your string.  Kudos.

Comment: WTF. I had the same issue. I copied the pathname again and it solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging your screen shot and the output, there is an invisible character at the start of the file path. That will cause .NET not to recognize it is an absolute path and automatically it will make it an absolute path itself.

If you use this code, you will notice that the inserted `?` causes the problem here:

```
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"?D:\some_file.ext");
```

Which outputs: `C:\Users\...\ConsoleApp8\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\?D:\some_file.ext`.

Instead of:

```
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"D:\some_file.ext");
```

Which outputs: `D:\some_file.ext`.

If you put your code in a HEX editor, you will see there is indeed a character before `D:`.

Comment: My bad, been trying to fix it for like more than an hour. I noticed the question mark character, felt like the runtime is adding it somehow. Thanks for the quick resolution, feeling bad that its a really small issue and I shouldn't have asked this. Silly me :(

Comment: No problem. Try to post your quoted path [here](http://asciivalue.com/index.php) and you will see the character.

Answer (score 2):

Thank goodness you cut and paste your original code!  I know you did because when I cut and paste your code I can see that you have invisible characters after the open quote and before the `D:\`.

These two lines **look identical but they're not!**  Cut and paste them if you don't believe me!

Your code:

```
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"‪D:\ScriptData\test.zip");
```

Fixed code:

```
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"D:\ScriptData\test.zip");
```

Here's what the binary editor shows.

[image]

You've got `E2 80 AA` secretly stuck in your source code file at the beginning of your filename.  Which happens to be the UTF-8 representation of the [LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm) character.

Comment: This is the correct diagnosis of the issue, am sorry that only one answer can be accepted. Thanks for helping me out.